# CSS3 advice, no images just css

Tags: css

Is it possible to create the following without use of images, just using css3?

[image]

Answer (score 15):

Yep. The relevant things you'll want to look up are gradients, text-shadow, and 2D transforms.

You'll need to do better with accepting answers to questions you've asked, and ask questions that show you've tried it yourself before you'll get better answers, most likely. People aren't going to give you the code if you've shown no effort to try to do it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible.

CSS border-radius, gradients, text-shadow and @font-face will get you quite a bit of the way.

Those angled tabs are going to be a massive pain to get right, and likely to have cross-browser issues. You'll probably be able to get them right using CSS `transform`, but it'll require separate DOM elements for the edges, otherwise you'll transform your text as well.

The outward curves at the bottom of the tabs will also be tricky. I can't see an easy way to achieve that.

Assuming your aim is to do it without images, rather than simply as a CSS excersise, then a better solution might be to do it using SVG. You can incorporate SVG as elements within your page, so no separate downloads, and it should be fairly straightforward to achieve the results you want -- certainly much easier than with pure CSS.

SVG won't work in older versions of IE (IE8 and below), but since you're asking about CSS3, I assume that's not an issue for you. If it is an issue, then you can use a library like [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) or [SVG2VML](http://code.google.com/p/svg2vml/) to convert the SVG into VML on the fly for IE.